# Why can't I center navbar

Tags: html, css

[nav image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiw1M.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans&display=swap');
:root {
  /* primary */
  --Orange: hsl(26, 100%, 55%);
  --Pale-orange: hsl(25, 100%, 94%);
  /* neutral */
  --Very-dark-blue: hsl(220, 13%, 13%);
  --Dark-grayish-blue: hsl(219, 9%, 45%);
  --Grayish-blue: hsl(220, 14%, 75%);
  --Light-grayish-blue: hsl(223, 64%, 98%);
  --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --Black: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  /* (with 75% opacity for lightbox background) */
}

html {
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* nav bar */

nav {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 7rem;
  background: rgb(201, 159, 159);
}


/* /////////////////////////// */

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(229, 22%, 53%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | E-commerce product page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-head">sneakers</div>
      <div class="navbar-links"></div>
      <div class="navbar-user"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="product-gallery"></div>

      <div class="product-info">
        <h5 class="product-origin">
          </h4>
          <h1 class="product-name">Fall Limited Sneakers</h1>
          <p class="product-description">These low-profile sneakers are your perfect casual wear companion. Featuring a durable rubber outer sole, they'll withstand everything the weather can offer.</p>

          <div class="product-pricetag">
            <div class="price-tag">
              <h5 class="price"></h5>
              <div class="discount"></div>
              <p class="price-original"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to make the navbar smaller than the viewport and center it but I cant seem to center the `nav` element's child which in this case its .navbar.
Adding margin or padding didnt work either because the div insist on sticking to the start of its parent
I also tried display: flex and place-items center, didnt work

Comment: Just add justify-content:center to your nav element.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).